# Remove css from an element while scrolling up

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm working on making a framework, where I need to show the navigation (prev/next) when second slide becomes active. Its happening correctly while scrolling down but now the case is that while scrolling up from down need to hide the navigation(prev/next) when the active from the second element(#box_two) gets removed. Please follow the link below:

http://52.88.196.216/test/index.html

Comment: Here you should add your code, when you ask a question

Comment: I'm sharing a link you can check directly from there, its an simple html file.

Comment: @VinayPatial You need to share the code not because the target link is simple but because it might not be permanent. StackOverflow is meant to be future-resistant and this question is not complete and does not contain information that could be useful in an "archival" way.

Answer (score 1):

Well first you would have to detect when the user scrolls up, and you would do that like so:

```
// contains the last value of the 
var lastScrollTop = 0;
// detect onscroll event
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  // store the current scroll value in a variable
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  // check if the current scroll is less than the last scroll
  // if so, then we're scrolling up, otherwise we're scrolling down
  if(scroll < lastScrollTop) {
    // the user is scrolling up do something awesome here...
  }
  // update the last scroll
  lastScrollTop = scroll;
});
```

Then you would have to remove the element's CSS, you could do this by removing a class, like this:

```
// get your element and remove the CSS class from it
$("div").removeClass("target-classname");
```

Instead of that you could also change the CSS of your element directly in jQuery, like this:

```
// changing multiple values at once
$("div").css({
  "property": "value"
});
// changing only one value
$("div").css("property", "value");
```

Put that all together and it would look like this:

```
// contains the last value of the 
var lastScrollTop = 0;
// detect onscroll event
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  // store the current scroll value in a variable
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  // check if the current scroll is less than the last scroll
  // if so, then we're scrolling up, otherwise we're scrolling down
  if(scroll < lastScrollTop) {
    // change the css of your div
    $("div").css("property", "value");
  }
  // update the last scroll
  lastScrollTop = scroll;
});
```

Without comments:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scroll < lastScrollTop) {
    $("div").css("property", "value");
  }
  lastScrollTop = scroll;
});
```

Of course you could turn the `scroll up / down` functions into a jQuery plug-in like so:

```
$.fn.scrollUp = function(callback) {
  // get the current element
  var self = $(this);
  // contains the last value of the 
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  // detect onscroll event
  self.scroll(function(event) {
    // store the current scroll value in a variable
    var scroll = self.scrollTop();
    // check if the current scroll is less than the last scroll
    // if so, then we're scrolling up, otherwise we're scrolling down
    if (scroll < lastScrollTop) {
      // call the callback
      callback.apply(self, [scroll]);
    }
    // update the last scroll
    lastScrollTop = scroll;
  });
};

$.fn.scrollDown = function(callback) {
  // get the current element
  var self = $(this);
  // contains the last value of the 
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  // detect onscroll event
  self.scroll(function(event) {
    // store the current scroll value in a variable
    var scroll = self.scrollTop();
    // check if the current scroll is less than the last scroll
    // if so, then we're scrolling up, otherwise we're scrolling down
    if (scroll > lastScrollTop) {
      // call the callback
      callback.apply(self, [scroll]);
    }
    // update the last scroll
    lastScrollTop = scroll;
  });
};
```

Then use them like this:

```
$(window).scrollUp(function(scroll) {
  // lets log the scroll amount here for example
  console.log(scroll);
  // note you can still use "this" and "$(this)" in here and they will correctly reference your element above (in this case "$(window)")
  $(this).find("body").html("You are scrolling up<br />" + "Scroll: " + scroll + "<br />");
});

$(window).scrollDown(function(scroll) {
  // lets log the scroll amount here for example
  console.log(scroll);
  // note you can still use "this" and "$(this)" in here and they will correctly reference your element above (in this case "$(window)")
  $(this).find("body").html("You are scrolling up<br />" + "Scroll: " + scroll + "<br />");
});
```

Using the jQuery plug-in you would end up with this:

```
// use the plug-in to detect the "scroll up" event
$(window).scrollUp(function(scroll) {
  // change the css of your element
  $("div").css("property", "value");
});
```

Without comments:

```
$(window).scrollUp(function(scroll) {
  $("div").css("property", "value");
});
```

Good luck and all the best.

Answer (score 0):

This code will remove class `className` out of `Selector` element

```
Selector.removeClass("className")
```